# Why does MATLAB use the average when doing array division?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, division

I have the following variables and code in MATLAB:

```
A = [ 2 2 2 2 2 ]
B = [ 1 2 3 4 5 ]
B / A % = 1.5
```

The answer, `1.5` is really the average of the values in B divided by 2, but why does MATLAB do this with these arrays and the `/` operator?

EDIT:

Looking at the documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html) near the bottom of the page for matrix right-division:

> x = B/A where xA = B

...but multiplying `x * A` above results in `[ 3 3 3 3 3 ]`. This does not seem to make sense either. Am I missing something here as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [right division operator `/` (or the `mrdivide` function)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html) will solve a systems of linear equations `xA = B` for `x`. From the above documentation link:

> If `A` is a rectangular `m`-by-`n` matrix with `m ~= n`, and `B` is a matrix with `n` columns, then `x = B/A` returns a least-squares solution of the system of equations `x*A = B`.

It's computing a value for `x` that best approximates a solution in a least-squares sense, since in this case you have an [underdetermined system of equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermined_system). There is no exact solution, so `x*A` doesn't exactly reproduce `B`.

Answer (score 4):

c = a/b perform **right-matrix division**. It is not the same as the division of ***each element***.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Matlab states that Right-Matrix division is `x = B/A where xA = b` and in the above code `x*A = [ 3 3 3 3 3 ]` which is not the same as B. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html near the bottom of the page. If I am confused on this as well let me know...

Comment: It is correct. I think you are misunderstanding matrix division, and the division of scalars. Perhaps read this:
http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-introduction.html
What behavior are you expecting?

Comment: OK that makes more sense. Thanks for the link.